# How to make PowerShell to interpret '<' symbol as part of user-specific command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run in powershell script an utility which takes '<' symbol as an argument:

```
utility.exe op1 < op2
```

But all I've got after performing this command is several black lines divided by newline symbols.

I tried to use `iex 'utility.exe op1 < op2'`

Running the same command in cmd.exe works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're going to face is that you're trying to replace the `<` operator with the standard input redirect operator from the standard command line.  That's not how PowerShell works.

You can try escaping it:

```
utility.exe op1 `< op2;
```

If you're on PowerShell 3.0, you can try the stop parsing operator:

```
utility.exe --% op1 < op2;
```

I doubt either of those will work since `utility.exe` is expecting something to redirect standard input.

Assuming `op2` is a filepath to a text file, you can try something like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'utility.exe' -ArgumentList 'op1' -RedirectStandardInput 'op2';
```

If I knew what you were actually trying to accomplish instead of requesting a general solution, I could be more precise.